# Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

`There is a similar popular question at` [MSE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-10-2012-12-2014).

The purpose of this thread is to help focus the attention of the community on posts that may require exceptional handling. This includes **requests for reopen and undeletion votes**. A request should be posted as an answer below.

Please do not use this thread to engage in debates on contentious matters (e.g. reasons for closure). That should be done in a separate linked thread. The goal is to keep this meta thread free of tension, so that everyone feels comfortable posting here. Please be polite, and respect the many different viewpoints in our diverse community.

Answer (score -3):

Request for reopening [This question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13836/is-there-a-law-that-require-all-countries-for-nuclear-disarmament):

The question put on hold. they say : *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s **hard to tell exactly what you're asking*** !!

I think the question is clear and is about existence of a law.